# Query in mysql for select statement

Tags: mysql

Can we run below query in mysql

```
SELECT rc.*,(SELECT * 
            from tbl_restaurantMenu 
            where menuCat = rc.id) 
as menu from tbl_restaurantMenuCat as rc;
```

If not how can we achieve similar result

Comment: yes we can run sub query in side main query.

Comment: did you try it to run in mysql?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that. When you use a subquery as a value, it must only return one column and one row, so you can't use `SELECT *`. You should use a `JOIN` instead.

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_restaurantMenuCat AS rc
LEFT JOIN menu AS m ON rc.id = m.menuCat
```

I used `LEFT JOIN` so that this will show restaurants even if they have no matching menus.

Answer (score 1):

`Select *` will not work this way. You should go for `JOIN`.

Try below query:

```
SELECT rc.*,rm.*
FROM tbl_restaurantMenuCat rc
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_restaurantMenu rm ON rc.id = rm.menuCat
```

Hope it helps!